# Are duplicates auto-deleted?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, auto-delete

Is there any condition that makes duplicates to be auto deleted at all? Or the duplicate status would protect of it:

> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - **not closed as a duplicate**
> - .....
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted

Comment: Duplicate is just a type of closed question, so it's quite trivial it would be auto deleted.

Comment: Yes, but most (including me) thinks the duplicated are not deleted at all.

Comment: Observed behaviour is that duplicates are deleted, but I'd still like to see an official SE answer.  On another SE site, even mods weren't sure if dups were nuked by the auto-delete.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is. There's another conditions that doesn't exclude duplicates that can cause deletion, namely:

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - **has −1 or lower score**
> - ...

So, yes, duplicated questions are deleted, so long they have been downvoted. To verify this just search `duplicate:yes score:..-1 answers:0 locked:0` and look for post older than 30 days, you will find none.